# use of sort in Z3

Tags: sorting, z3, z3py, theorem-proving

Can somebody help to know how to use "for all" correctly in Z3, Ive been looking in the documentation but I couldnt find information. What I am trying to do is

within "foo" I need say in Z3 something to the equivalent of

"let (u,r) be runnable(t) in { (assert ((u,r) is in users) (assert (r,t) is in roles)) }"

What I don't know is how to take the first element in runnable to assert that is in users, and then the  second element to assert that is in roles.

---

(declare-sort Task)
(declare-sort Role)
(declare-sort User)
(declare-fun runnable (Task) (User Role))
(declare-fun perm (Role Task) Bool)
(declare-fun users (User Role) Bool)

(assert (forall (t Task)) (foo))

(check-sat)
(get-model)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is not well-formed SMT2, functions can not return multiple objects. The [Z3 Guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide) for examples of how to use datatypes as well as quantifiers.

Comment: Thank you Christoph I think I should start there then.